# Cannot right align a checkbox in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]

I am trying to design as per the above image. I tried with Grid Layout and also tried with nested Linear Layout. In both ways checkbox is not right aligned. It is displaying just after the text1

Can someone help on this.

The code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="2dp"
tools:context="com.example.user.recycleview.MainActivity">

<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:src="@drawable/cappuccino"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="@string/cappuccino"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/price"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2" />

</GridLayout>


<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

With the above code it is displaying as in the below:

[image]

If the Text1 part is too long, the checkbox is going out of the screen, as in the below image

[image]

Comment: use relative layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a single `RelativeLayout`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:padding="2dp"
    tools:context="com.example.user.recycleview.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/somepngfile"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checkbox"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="This is two line text for your large title This is two line text for your large title"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_price"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/text_title"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/text_title"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/text_title"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Price: 150.00"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Ferdous, this is also working and looks simple as it is using only relative layout. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If my answer seems useful then please give an up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use layout_weight to align checkbox right,

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkItem"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative layout for you list item . Try below code

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="end" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/checkbox"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView"
    android:layout_weight=".8"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="@string/cappuccino" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@string/price" />
</LinearLayout>


<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is may helpful to you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="2dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_image" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_row="0"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="Sample Header" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_row="1"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="Sample Desc" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>


<View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

</LinearLayout>
```